# Did George Lucas try to acquire the rights to 'The Lord Of The Rings' / 'The Hobbit'?

Tags: cinema-history, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit, willow

[image: George Lucas] <sup>[[Source](http://vimeo.com/13075648)]</sup>

[This review](http://www.craigerscinemacorner.com/Reviews/willow.htm) of the movie [***Willow***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096446/), which was produced by [George Lucas](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000184/), claims:

> George Lucas was desperately attempting to secure the rights to the [***Lord of the Rings***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings) series and its prequel, [***The Hobbit***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hobbit), for years and hoped to make it his next epic series post-STAR WARS.

[This page](http://hardcoregaming101.net/willow/willow.htm) on *Willow* computer games makes the same claim:

> It should also be noted that *Willow* was originally intended to be a film adaptation of *The Hobbit*, but George Lucas could not procure the rights to the Tolkien franchises.

The [Wikipedia page on ***Willow***](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Willow_%28film%29&oldid=514073844#Development) also used to say:

> Lucas was originally going to do a film of JRR Tolkien's *The Hobbit*. But he was unable to get the rights.

But **this has since been edited out** because no source was provided.

**My Question:**

- Did George Lucas once try to acquire the rights to *The Lord of the Rings* and/or *The Hobbit*,
  or is this an unfounded rumour?

Comment: A (humorous) comparison between _Willow_ and _LOTR_ can be watched [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qAF1NDyyWgs)

Comment: We can all be thankful that he did not succeed.  Good question though, it would be nice to find a definitive source for this. +1

Comment: @iandotkelly Yeah, just imagine *Lucas* after some years of *The Lord of the Rings*' amazing success coming up with the idea for *LotR: Episode I - III*, which would suddenly get mixed reviews from *LotR* fans. Wait, what? ;-)

Comment: Willow was an amazing movie, I think GL could have done a really good job with LOTR and/or The Hobbit.

Answer (score 11):

I asked this question on Facebook to a couple of friends of mine ([Pablo Hidalgo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Pablo_Hidalgo), content manager and author for Lucasfilm, and [Mark Newbold](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mark_Newbold), writer for Star Wars Insider) and as far as they know, this rumor isn't true.

Lucas certainly saw Tolkien's work as an influence, but he didn't actively seek to acquire the rights.

Comment: Now the question is, have they heard him say _"No, that's not true"_ or have they just never heard him say _"Yes, that's true."_ The latter would leave open a possibility, but the first would definately confirm that the rumour is wrong.

Comment: Good point, Oliver. That said, these guys know everything there is to know about George and the company, so I'll trust I'll their judgement. But you are correct, this isn't conclusive.

Answer (score 5):

It would appear to me that those claims could be true, because researching the subject in Google found many references to George Lucas and Lord of the Rings. You have to also accept that George would have the financial ability to purchase such rights, and he is clearly a huge fan of Tolkien's work.

George is referenced in this FOX News report as being close friends with director Peter Jackson.

> Lucas also told me that he and Lord of the Rings director Peter Jackson have become good friends, commiserating with each other in Australia and New Zealand on their shoots about making their two series.

Read more: http://www.foxnews.com/story/0,2933,75540,00.html

Also, in this [StarWars Origins](http://www.moongadget.com/origins/lotr.html) website. I found the following.

> Lucas has often cited The Lord of the Rings as a major influence on Star Wars. The superficial stuff is the most obvious, but the subtle lesson Lucas learned from Tolkien is how to handle the delicate stuff of myth.

LOTR is a reoccurring theme when Goerge is interviewed. So I think this makes this myth possible that he once tried to purchase the rights.

Comment: Just as an aside, I asked this question on Facebook to a couple of friends of mine who are fairly high up in the Lucasfilm ranks, and they claimed that this rumor isn't true. Lucas certainly saw Tolkien's work as an influence, but he didn't actively seek to acquire the rights.

Comment: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: I don't remember where I read it, but I think Lucas and Jackson became friends _after_ the LotR movies came out.